# client side javascript to access shared Google Calendar via service acct with no login

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have a client side Javascript solution that is to access a shared Google Calendar via a Service Account.

I have created the Calendar, Service Acct and shared the Calendar with the Service Acct.

I do NOT want the user to have to enter any usernames/passwords in the process.

I want to query the Calendar for events, display the available/unavailable times to the user, allow the user to pick an available time and then programmatically create an event starting at the selected time.

I've seen server side solutions written in Java or PHP but would prefer to have all this done in client side Javascript.  I think, but am not totally sure, the client side restriction removes the possibility of using Node.js as it is, I think, a kind of server side Javascript - but I don't know for certain.

Is a completely client side, Javascript solution THAT DOES NOT require entering a username/password even possible?  I see hints that it may be, but I cannot see exactly how to construct it.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might (just) be possible, but since it involves the client holding the OAuth credentials, it's a really bad idea.

You've said "THAT DOES NOT require entering a username/password". How will you be authenticating the user?

Comment: The app is to allow people to book appointments at a business.  They view the calendar, see the available times and sign up for one.  Thru a little bit of magic, I prevent them from deleting existing entries.

One of the things the user will have to enter (but that I will NOT display) is a phone number so the business owner can ask them where they are if they do not show up for an appointment.  So, I suppose that provides some amount of authentication of the individual.

Comment: My 2c is to do this server side, either using a small Appengine servlet, or Apps Script

Comment: truthfully i'm starting to think server side would be the easier way to go.